# Set flex items spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have three flex elements, in a container, which are aligned to the center. How to some spacing betwee the items? For example: the first should be shoen to the left of the container, the second to the center and the third to the right.  Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/usernamenn/y1L6k5ap/
Here's the code:

```
.herodownload {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    margin-top: 90px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.android {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.ios {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.windows {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

/* end hero download */

```
<div class="herodownload"> <!-- hero download -->
        <div id="android"><img src="images/vignetta.png"></div>
        <div id="ios"><img src="images/vignetta.png"></div>
        <div id="windows"><img src="images/vignetta.png"></div>
            <div class="downlad_buttons">
                <div id=""></div>
                <div id=""></div>
                <div id=""></div>
            </div>
    </div>  
     <!-- end main site content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) instead of `justify-content: center` since the latter will align the items to the center as a whole.

`space-between` allows equal margin between the flex children. You can also use `space-around` if you need equal padding/margin within the container in addition to the equal margin between flex children.

**Modified Output:**

```css
/* homepage heading and paragraph style */

.hero_description {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}
#hero_heading {
  font-size: 6em;
}
#hero_paragraph {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  margin-top: -55px;
}
/* end homepage heading and paragraph*/

/* hero download */

.herodownload {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  margin-top: 90px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Modified */
}
.android {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.ios {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.windows {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/* end hero download */
```

```html
<div class="herodownload">
  <!-- hero download -->
  <div id="android">
    <img src="images/vignetta.png">
  </div>
  <div id="ios">
    <img src="images/vignetta.png">
  </div>
  <div id="windows">
    <img src="images/vignetta.png">
  </div>
  <div class="downlad_buttons">
    <div id=""></div>
    <div id=""></div>
    <div id=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end main site content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used `id` for the android, ios and windows divs, you have to use `#android`, `#ios`, and `#windows` in the CSS file instead of using `.android`, `.ios`, and `.windows`.

Comment: Yeah, your right. I've update them as ids instead of classes and i forgot to change the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Good resource for flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://jsfiddle.net/pbunsee/ce6jrLdg/

I used the following:

```
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
```

To get the result though I commented out the button divs `<div class="downlad_buttons">`
Since the download buttons appear sequentially together with the image divs in the herodownload div, all the button and image divs are being spaced at equal distance from each other but visually the effect does not look centered due to the empty button divs.

Either add content into the button divs 
or 
add jQuery on-click event listener to the image divs so that the buttons will no longer be necessary.